# Correct setup for Azure B2C and Core 3.1 API

Tags: .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to protect my API and ensure that my WebApp is only able to access it if it has proper token.

I followed the tutorial to setup a nodejs and it works fine, now i am trying to apply the same settings to a Dotnet Core 3.1 Web Api I, however the tutorial for dotnet core is horrendous. I've gone through a few examples and nothing has come close.

I've got the current setup in my Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Authority"];
                options.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Audience"];
            });

            services.AddControllers();
        }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

and in my appsettings.json

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
      "Audience": "c6exxx-xxxxxxxx",
      "Authority": "https://XXX.b2clogin.com/XX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_SUSI_POLICY/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration/"
    }
```

Yet when i call from my WebApp (which is a SPA) always get a 401.

```
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
​
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/hello: 401 Unauthorized"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 401
​
statusText: "Unauthorized"
​
url: "http://localhost:5000/hello"
```

Again same information as per nodejs sample here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=app-reg-ga) just ported into Dotnetcore 3.1 webapi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've left out `UseAuthentication()` that actually triggers authentication in the back-end:

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication(); // This line
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **AzureAdB2C:Authority** should be set to `https://XXX.b2clogin.com/XX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_SUSI_POLICY/v2.0`. [The JWT bearer authentication middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/983e7ed635f4d128edce4191b51869bd7be8aced/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerPostConfigureOptions.cs#L37) appends `/.well-known/openid-configuration` to this base URL when retrieving the OpenID Connect configuration from Azure AD B2C.

Secondly, ensure that **AzureAdB2C:Audience** is referring to the client identifier for your API application.